# Read 3rd line of file and then every

Tags: python, readfile

I have a huge file which looks like this:

```
Name: Block of line 1
Data: Block of line 2
**Important line 3**
Not important line 4
Not important line 5
**Another important line 6**
Not important line 7

Name: Block of line 1
Data: Block of line 2
**Important line 3**
Not important line 4
Not important line 5
**Another important line 6**
Not important line 7

Name: Block of line 1
Data: Block of line 2
**Important line 3**
Not important line 4
Not important line 5
**Another important line 6**
Not important line 7
```

In python I want to read every 3rd and 6th line *or when I use .read() that would make it line 2 and 5*

My code only prints the first block, so ideally I would like to loop over it:

```
files = open(fo, 'r')
for i, line in enumerate(files):
    if i == 2:
    print line
elif i == 5:
        print line
        break
```

Comment: More imformations would be useful. Which language? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, in python. At the moment I can only print the first time but I can't seem to figure out a way to loop over it and continue getting the lines I want until the file ends. Hope this clears things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files = open(fo, 'r')
for i, line in enumerate(files):
    if i%8 == 2:
        print line
    elif i%8 == 5:
        print line
```

That should work, This takes `i` mod 8 because it appears that each block is 8 lines long. Not the best solution, you should probably keep your data in a slightly neater format.

Or even simpler:

```
files = open(fo, 'r')
for i, line in enumerate(files):
    if i%8 == 2 or i%8 == 5:
        print line
```

Comment: how about `if not ((i+1)%8)%3:`

Comment: @xcorat why? that seems a lot more complicated. If you want it to be simpler why not `if i%8 == 2 or i%8 == 5:`?

Comment: since there's only one comparison there, it's faster i think

Comment: I find that unlikely and it is a lot more convoluted. If you really need this to be faster I would recommend not writing it in python.

Comment: The file is compiled somewhere else, I have no input how the file is compiled. This worked for me. Thank you very much

Comment: If some of the blocks change sometimes, instead of 7 lines 8 or even less like 6 lines. How can this be done? Doing the i mod total wouldn't work.

Comment: It's going to start getting a lot more complex, bascially you will want to read in the entire chunk of data and then do some logic on it.